# Python: adding to Excel conditional formatting of type 'containsText'

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I am trying to add conditional formatting (highlight cell containing pipe character) to Excel using openpyxl (2.5.4) in Python 2.7. I have tried with many variants of code as seen below. None of it worked. Can you point where is error?

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import formatting, styles, Workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('export.xlsx')
sheet = wb['all']

red_text = Font(color='9C0006')
red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor='FFC7CE')
```

#### Variant 1 - code

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', rule(type='containsText', operator='containsText', text='|', fill=red_fill, font=red_text))
```

#### Variant 1 - error

```
NameError: name 'rule' is not defined
```

#### Variant 2 - code

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', CellIsRule(type='containsText', operator='containsText', text='|', fill=red_fill, font=red_text))
```

#### Variant 2 - error

```
TypeError: CellIsRule() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

#### Variant 3 - code

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(type='containsText', operator='containsText', text='|', fill=red_fill, font=red_text))
```

#### Variant 3 - error

```
TypeError: CellIsRule() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

#### Variant 4 - code

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='containsText', text='|', fill=red_fill, font=red_text))
```

#### Variant 4 - error

```
TypeError: CellIsRule() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl import styles
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule

red_colour = 'ffc7ce'
red_colour_font = '9c0103'

red_font = styles.Font(size=14, bold=True, color=red_colour_font)
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=red_colour, end_color=red_colour, fill_type='solid')

rule = Rule(type='containsText', text='|', stopIfTrue=True)
rule.dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=red_font, border=None, fill=red_fill)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', rule)
```

This is using openpyxl version 3.0.

This is how I am creating a textContains conditional formatting rule.

Comment: This works, almost. The conditional formatting is in the file, but not applied until I explicitly go into the document, manage/edit (no changes)/apply the rule. Any idea how I can activate this automatically, or what I am missing?

Comment: @Levon - I have the same issue. Did you happen to find a solution? Thx!

Comment: @KJH No, unfortunately not. I end up going into the file, and just double-clicking the cell with the conditional formatting at the top of the column and it applies it to the rest of the column. Not ideal, but workable, esp since I have to open the file anyway.

Comment: @Levon,I ran into this same problem and could only fix it by using `type='expression'` instead and setting `formula=['ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|", A1:E4))']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the samples given on the site?

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html

For example here is one I am using:

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B2:B23',
             CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['-100'], stopIfTrue=True, 
fill=redFill))
```

Here is the function itself:

```
def CellIsRule(operator=None, formula=None, stopIfTrue=None, font=None, border=None, 
fill=None)
```

Notice the arguments (Operator, Formula, stopIfTrue, font, border, fill)

type & text are not arguments. In your case you likely need something like:

```
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:E4', 
formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='containsText', formula=['|'], fill=red_fill, 
font=red_text))
```

I will be honest with the latest versions of Office this doesn't all work as smoothly as older versions. Make sure you are using a supported version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the example in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html) actually has an example of **containsText**:

```
>>> # Highlight cells that contain particular text by using a special formula
>>> red_text = Font(color="9C0006")
>>> red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
>>> dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=red_text, fill=red_fill)
>>> rule = Rule(type="containsText", operator="containsText", text="highlight", dxf=dxf)
>>> rule.formula = ['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("highlight",A1)))']
>>> ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:F40', rule)
```

It's pretty hacky/horrible, I had to add that formula with the A1 reference updated appropriately to make it work. Without it the conditional formatting rule would appear correctly inside the generated Excel file but it wouldn't actually work until I edited the rule. Perhaps the internal Excel representation actually has something like that formula in it.